# "Осоловевший" — происхождение слова

Tags: этимология

"Осоловевший" — говорят о расслабившемся, о том, кому лень двигаться. Например, "объелся и осоловел".
А откуда вообще происходит это слово?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

СОЛОВЕТЬ
СОЛОВЕ́ТЬ, соловею, соловеешь, несовер.

1. (совер. посоловеть). Становиться соловым, более соловым (спец.). Жеребец соловеет.
2. (совер. посоловеть) перен. О глазах, взгляде: становиться мутным, невыразительным (при опьянении, болезни; прост.).
3. (совер. осоловеть) перен. О человеке: становиться вялым, сонным (от опьянения, усталости; прост.).

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

Этимология. СОЛОВЕТЬ. Искон. Суф. образование от соловый "серый, желтоватый", общеслав. производного посредством суф. -в- от той же основы (sol-), что и др.-в.-нем. salo "темный, грязный", ирл.  salach "грязный", лат. saliva "слюна" и др. См. осоветь.

Кстати, слово СОЛОВЕЙ  имеет исторически тот же корень. Этимология
СОЛОВЕЙ. Общеслав. Суф. производное (суф. -иj- > -ей) от солвь "серый, желтоватый" (после развития полногласия > соловый). См. соловеть. Птица названа по цвету своего оперения.
Яндекс.Словари › Этимологический словарь, 2004

Яндекс.Словари › Этимологический словарь, 2004

Comment: Во всей это истории непонятно только, почему именно у этого слова оказались эти два переносных значения. 
Особенно последнее. Какая связь у пьяного с соловым, тем более - соловьем...

Comment: Я с соловьем тоже связи не вижу. Просто когда смотрела этимологию "соловый", решила и "соловья" посмотреть. 
  А почему такие переносные значения... Тут еще 2 интересных рассуждения ниже. Люблю, когда есть обоснованные варианты (мой менее обоснованный, так, больше предположение/наблюдение).

Answer (score 3):

Соловый жеребец - конечно же, о цвете - сером, желтовато-сером. А вот осоловевший взгляд и человек - другое значение.Глаз соловый  - желтовато-серый, а взгляд в диалектах - мутный, бессмысленный. Это значение - от слова "сова".У совы глаза желтоватые, а когда она спит - стеклянные, бессмысленные. Осоветь - стать таким, как сова во сне. Слова осоветь и осоловеть близки и по звучанию, и по значению (глаза спящей совы и желтоватые, и бессмысленные, мутные), вот они и соединились в двух из значений, в разговорной речи стали синонимами.Диалектные слова часто проникают даже в литературный язык, не только в просторечия.

Comment: Вообще-то соловая масть - это золотисто-рыжий корпус и белая грива. Серого там никакого нет. Вот классическая соловая лошадь: http://s13.radikal.ru/i186/1112/2c/c6ddac168b28.jpg